# how to use two thens or get two answers in fetch json

Tags: javascript

I'm searching for an image and name by Rick&Morty's api, I've already been successful with a photo and name, but I want the method to return one more image, totaling two images of the characters and their names.

```js
gerarValorAleatorio = () => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 671);
}

pegarPersonagem = () => {
    let numeroAleatorio = gerarValorAleatorio();
    return fetch(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/${numeroAleatorio}`, {
        method:'GET',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            "Content-type": 'application/json'
        }
        
    }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        imagem.src = data.image;
        imagem.alt = data.name;
        nomeDoPersonagem = data.name;
        nome.innerHTML = `${nomeDoPersonagem}`;

        imagem2.src = data.image;
        imagem2.alt = data.name;
        nomeDoPersonagem = data.name;
        nome2.innerHTML = `${nomeDoPersonagem}`;
```

Comment: You need to make two fetch requests

Answer (score 1):

The [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) is based on promises. So it means you can group fetch calls in an array and use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for their completion.

When the data is returned (as an array) you can iterate over it.

```js
function fetchAPI(n) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res(`Done ${n}`);
    }, 2000)
  });
}

const arr = [fetchAPI(1), fetchAPI(2)];

Promise.all(arr).then(data => {
  data.forEach(str => console.log(str));
});
```